# Timer based reminder in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, timer, notifications, push, reminders

My app asks the user to fill in and save a form locally. I want him to be reminded 48 hrs after the app has been closed that he has a pending form. 
Is push notification the only way out? Does it cost money to use a provisioning service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iPhone OS 4 adds timer-based alerting for apps that aren't running. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/iphone/whats-new.html#multitasking) for a brief description. I'm guessing this means that push notifications are your only option prior to version 4.

Comment: Care to tick it as the accepted answer? (I'm shooting for 10k rep today! :-)

Comment: Thanks a million; that got me over the line! :-) :-) :-)